# Error: "The template variable 'docker.image.prefix' has no value"

Tags: docker, spring-boot

Failed to execute goal `com.spotify:docker-maven-plugin:0.4.0:build (default-cli)` on project `systodo`:

```
Exception caught: The template variable 'docker.image.prefix' has no value
```

Comment: please provide us more information. How does your `pom.xml` look like and your `Dockerfile` and what did exactly do?

Answer (score 5):

since you havent given much info regarding your problem i assume that you are following a guide to create a docker image and are stuck.

I found myself in the same position and i think i have found a solution that should satisfy a lot of people that are searching for this issue.

I in particular followed this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/).

The issue was that i only added the plugin to the pom.
But i also had to add a property to make it work.

```
<properties>
   <docker.image.prefix>springio</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                <buildArgs>
                    <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                </buildArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```